# Catching errors in Electron Printing

Tags: javascript, electron, printing-web-page

The print dialog doesn't seem to appear when I have no printers attached with electron's built in printing. Right now I wait for the webpage to load then I print the page but no print message is displayed and no print error is displayed. I print dialog does appear I have a printer attached but doesn't appear and gives no error message when I don't.

```
win.webContents.on('did-finish-load', function() {
    try {
        console.log('Print Message: ', win.webContents.print({silent: false}));         
    }
    catch(e) {
        console.log('Print Error: ', e);
    }
});
```

Is there a way to check if the print dialog opened or the user has no printer available? Or even catch errors in electron printing?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Is there any way to then just check if there is a printer attached in javascript then?

Comment: You could [check if the user has any printers](https://github.com/tojocky/node-printer) using a separate module.

Comment: @MikeC node-printer doesn't seem to be package-able with electron since I got it to work on my local machine but wasn't able to build it and put it in an exe since the Visual Studio and Python dependencies

Comment: @KobeBryant Check out [this issue](https://github.com/tojocky/node-printer/issues/113) which may address that problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a function as callback and get the response that includes error if execution is not successful.

```
win.webContents.print(options, (success, errorType) => {
  // if error, log error reason
  if (!success) console.log(errorType)
})
```

You can also use ***win.webContents.getPrinters*** to get system printer list.

[webContents Print](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-contents#contentsprintoptions-callback)

[Get Printers](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-contents#contentsgetprinters)